# CakePHP - How to update multiple records

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I update a single field of multiple records in CakePHP?

I retrieve multiple records using `$this->Item->find('all')` and I need to set different values for each of them and save. I do

```
$items = $this->Item->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('Item.id', 'Item.order'),
    'conditions'=> array(
        'Item.project_id =' => $this->request->params['project_id'],
    ),
    'order' => array ('Item.order ASC')
));

foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    $item->saveField('Item.order', rand(1, 10));
}
```

but it raises an error saying

> Fatal error: Call to a member function saveField() on a non-object

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Update:** Please note that this is an old answer meant for CakePHP 1.3. For a modern approach please refer to [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18255526/227992).

Try this

```
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    $this->Item->id = $item['Item']['id'];
    $this->Item->saveField('order', rand(1, 10));
}
```

Comment: See [@hugofcampos's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18255526/216084) for performance.

Comment: With the introduction of [Model::saveMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array) in CakePHP 2.0, refer to @hugofcampos's answer for a better approach to this.

Comment: @HamidNazari I think this will not be good if there is thousands of fields it's not recommended

Answer (score 18):

I would say that you should use [CakePHP Save Many](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array) to improve the performance.

Ex:

```
$data = array(
    array( 'Item' => array('id' => 2, 'order' => rand(1,5)) ),
    array( 'Item' => array('id' => 3, 'order' => rand(1,5)) ),
);
$Model->saveMany($data, array('deep' => true));
```

Comment: How can we use saveMany in CakePHP 3 ?

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing wrong is that `$item` is not an Object (nor is `items` btw), so you cannot call any methods on this. `$items` is just an array with all the results from your `find()` operation.

What you need to do is use the `saveAll()` method and use it on a proper object, `$this->Item` in this case.

See the bottom part of this page from [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/75/Saving-Your-Data) for more info.